Terraform vsphere - Need to attach external disk to existing vm
I have two folders - instance and volume.
instance 
 -main.tf
volume
 -main.tf
 -volume.tf

I am defining the instance folder main.tf as
data "vsphere_datacenter" "datacenter" {
  name = "dc-01"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "datastore-01"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = "cluster-01"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "VM Network"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name             = "foo"
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  num_cpus         = 1
  memory           = 1024
  guest_id         = "otherLinux64Guest"
  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id
  }
  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 20
  }
}
} 

with single disk. But I need two additional disks which I am defining separately in volume folder - volume.tf
   module host {
   source "../instance"
  }

-volume.tf
data "vsphere_datacenter" "datacenter" {
  name = "dc-01"
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "datastore" {
  name = "datastore-01"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_disk" "virtual_disk1" {
  size               = 40
  type               = "thin"
  vmdk_path          = "/foo/foo.vmdk"
  create_directories = true
  datacenter         = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.name
  datastore          = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.name
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_disk" "virtual_disk2" {
  size               = 40
  type               = "thin"
  vmdk_path          = "/foo/foo.vmdk"
  create_directories = true
  datacenter         = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.name
  datastore          = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.name
}


Now in volumes.tf, I want to define some code through which I can attach these 2 disks to instance created in instance folder main.tf. I do not see any documentation to attach external disks to newly created server in other folder.

To attach additional disks from the volume folder to the VM in the instance folder, follow these steps:
1. In instance/main.tf:
Add an output for the VM ID so it can be referenced later.
output "vm_id" {
  value = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.id
}

2. In volume/volume.tf:
Reference the VM and attach the new disks using vsphere_virtual_disk_attachment.
module "host" {
  source = "../instance"
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  id = module.host.vm_id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_disk_attachment" "attach_disk1" {
  virtual_machine_id = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.id
  disk_id            = vsphere_virtual_disk.virtual_disk1.vmdk_path
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_disk_attachment" "attach_disk2" {
  virtual_machine_id = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.id
  disk_id            = vsphere_virtual_disk.virtual_disk2.vmdk_path
}

This way, the disks from volume will attach to the VM created in instance.

Thanks for your response. I am getting error - Provider Hashicorp/vsphere does not support resource vsphere_virtual_disk_attachment.
